# Salto de línea en variable en SdPanel GX

Tags: android, genexus

Como hago que una variable en un SdPanel GeneXus haga un salto de linea?

Tengo un problema con una variable en un sd panel. Estoy usando el generador android en GX17u8.

Si pongo una variable por ej character(150) en una grilla con la propiedad Autogrow en TRUE, la variable hace un salto de linea y continua el texto abajo. Como dice en la wiki https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?20204,Auto+Grow+property

Pero ésto mismo no funciona en una variable que no está en una grilla. Si yo pongo esa misma variable en modo editable, con la misma clase y las mismas propiedades sobre una tabla y comienzo a escribir o seteo un texto, no hace salto de línea sino que hace un scroll del texto dentro del cuadro de la variable.

He intentado cambiar las propiedades de la varaible, de la tabla y de la clase y de ninguna manera logré hacer un salto de línea.

Puenden intentar crear un sd panel y poner una variable character(150) y escribir y verán que no hace salto de línea como en una grilla.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Lo que podes hacer es darle un tamaño fixeado a la row que contiene el campo. Ahi vas a poder ver el campo mas grande y al escribir hace el salto de linea, al acabarse el espacio, va a hacer eso que mencionas, scroll sobre el contenedor. Capaz eso te sirve.

Comment: Gracias por contestar @chona , intenté poner un tamaño fijo a la row y modificar las propiedades de autogrow pero sigue haciendo el scroll horizontal y no un salto de línea y scroll vertical sobre la tabla como yo quiero.